# Angular 17: Bootstrap5 modal launch on page load

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5, angular17-ssr

I am using Angular 17 and Bootstrap 5 to launch a modal on page load.
I was able to launch the modal on button click but when I tried hiding the button and launching the modal, received an error

> document is not defined

My Modal.HTML file

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="staticBackdrop"
  data-bs-backdrop="static"
  data-bs-keyboard="false"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5 text-dark" id="staticBackdropLabel">
          Select User
        </h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-dark">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="flexRadioDefault"
            id="User1"
            value="User 1"
            (change)="onRadioChange($event)"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="User1"> User 1 </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="flexRadioDefault"
            id="User2"
            value="User 2"
            (change)="onRadioChange($event)"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="User2"> User 2 </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="flexRadioDefault"
            id="User3"
            value="User 3"
            (change)="onRadioChange($event)"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="User3"> User 3 </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="flexRadioDefault"
            id="User4"
            value="User 4"
            (change)="onRadioChange($event)"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="User4"> User 4 </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="flexRadioDefault"
            id="User5"
            value="User 5"
            (change)="onRadioChange($event)"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="User5"> User 5 </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Component.TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup-modal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './popup-modal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './popup-modal.component.scss',
})
export class PopupModalComponent {
  selectedUser: string = '';

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const modalElement = document.getElementById(
      'staticBackdrop'
    ) as HTMLElement;
    const modal = new Modal(modalElement);
    modal.show();
  }

  onRadioChange(event: any) {
    this.selectedUser = event.target.value;
    this.cookieService.set('CurrentUser', this.selectedUser);
    console.log(this.cookieService.get('CurrentUser'));
  }
}
```

Error:
[image]

I have recently moved from Next.js to Angular. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: You need to move your modal initialization code to AfterViewInit. Otherwise the DOM won't be ready. Speaking from prior experience... you'll also want to import Modal from the exact import instead of `bootstrap` as this can cause other JavaScript not to work. I would strongly suggest taking a look at ng-bootstrap instead of working with Bootstrap's JS directly.